# Intersección y diferencia entre ABBs balanceados C++

Tags: c++, árboles-binarios

Necesito hacer dos funciones sobre ABB Balanceados en C++:

-intersección (dados dos arboles ABBs devolver otro arbol nuevo con los datos que coincidan)
-diferencia (dados dos arboles ABBs devolver otro arbol nuevo solo con los elementos que estan en b1 y no en b2)

```
struct ABB {
  int dato;
  ABB *izq;
  ABB *der;
};

typedef ABB *binario;

binario interseccion(binario b1, binario b2);

binario diferencia(binario b1, binario b2);
```

Hasta ahora probé aplanando los arboles a listas, luego intersectandolas o diferenciandolas y despues convirtiendo de nuevo a arbol y si bien funciona, mi código no cumple con el orden que me piden en el obligatorio.

El tiempo de ejecucion es O(n1 + n2 + n.log n), siendo n1 y n2 la cantidad de elementos de b1 y b2 respectivamente y n la del binario resultado.

Si me pueden ayudar les agradezco!